# Why in the Spark UI query view the number of output rows is showing a wrong number when reading a hive metastore table?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading a metastore table that have the data stored in Parquet files which have around 1 million records but somehow in
the query view on the stage that scans the number of rows is reading a ridiculous much larger amount of records (over 200 million) which keeps growing during the process (see screenshot below). This does not make sense.

I validated many times the number of records printing .count() and also querying directly in Hive, and definitely, the number is 1 million.

[image]

This is the query that I'm using to read the file within the spark job:

```
joined_pointx = spark.sql("""SELECT c.unique_reference_number, c.name, c.brand, c.pointx_classification_name, c.lat, c.long, CAST(d.poi_radious_meters as INT) as poi_radious_meters
  FROM adp_uk.pointx as c INNER JOIN temp.pointx_category d ON c.pointx_classification_code = d.category_code""")
```

where **adp_uk.pointx** is the table that I'm reading.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What says spark if you call `spark.table("adp_uk.pointx").count()`?

Comment: It gives the correct number: 1 million.

Comment: And what do you see on graph inside WebUI when you run the `count()` job? Still ~300M records on Scan parquet?

Comment: Still facing this strange behaviour and still no answer to the question.